# How to deny cloning of a repository from gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

We're currently migrating our repositories - one after the other - to a different server.
Therefore I want to deny cloning of a repository once it has been migrated to make sure the user will get an **error message** if he or she tries to clone it.

So far I could only achieve that goal half-way: I was able to deny reading of any branches. However the clone itself won't give any error message. It prints following warning instead:

```
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Currently the permissions for this repository are inherited from a global permission scheme which grants the read access for the groups we're members of.

What I therefore tried was:

- DENY `Read` access to

  - `refs/*`
  - `refs/heads/*`
  - `refs/tags/*`

Somehow it won't give my an error like 'permission denied' which I would like to see.

Is there a way to achieve that in gerrit without changing the global permission scheme?
Do I possibly need to inherit the permissions from a different permission scheme?

Comment: Why do not you just set the repository to "Hidden" state?

Comment: Remove the files and update the README(.md|.asciidoc) to point at the new server?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira: Sounds good. How could I do that?

Comment: @DavidK: Thanks for the proposal I'll consider that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best strategy is to set the repository state to "Hidden". This way the repository is hidden and only visible to project owners. Other users are not able to see the repository even if they have read permissions granted on the repository.

See more info about repository deletion [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html#project-deletion) and about repository state [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#project-state).